# Create Graph that can actively subtract certain variables

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a base value, let say 'Total Groceries Bought' (monthly) as well as sub variables that include exactly how much was bought of certain groceries, such as fruit, crackers, vegetables, etc. Is there any way to graph the variable 'Total Groceries Bought" (it will be graphed against month) and then create a filter that will subtract certain types of groceries that I do not want to be included in the total? I want it to actively change the graph I would have displayed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does your data look like? What have you tried?

Comment: If you columns look similar to: Date (Month), Sub-Variable, Amount, then you could easily Pivot your data. Then create a pivot chart. Then use a pivot slicer or the pivot filter to de-select what you don't want to include in the pivot calculations.